# Saving custom data via ajax with nonces

Tags: plugins, nonce

I'm trying to securely save custom data to database from plugin backend via ajax.

JavaScript code that runs after clicking save button:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action : 'myPluginDataSave',
        someData: 'blabla',
        myPluginNonce : ajaxVars.nonce
    },
    complete: function(data) {          
        console.log('finish',data.responseText);
    }
});
```

PHP code (some parts are missing), ajax_save_data function receives data from JS code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myPluginDataSave', array(&$this, 'ajax_save_data') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugn-js' );
wp_localize_script( 'my-plugn-js', 'ajaxVars', array(
                    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myPluginNonce' ),                          
)); 

function ajax_save_data() {
    if ( !isset($_POST['myPluginNonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myPluginNonce'], 'myPluginNonce' ) ) 
        die ( 'you cant do this' ); 

    echo 'here data gets saved to DB' . $_POST['someData'];

    die();
}
```

Hooks are added only in admin (inside `is_admin()` if statement). Save button can be clicked multiple times (without page refresh).

Code works. But, my question: is this correct way to do this? Do I need nonce there?

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `is_admin` conditional statement which is why you should include it in your snippet so we can properly assess what you are attempting to do outside of the obvious question.

Either way a nonce should be mandatory. That function that receives and processes your AJAX request/response should also verify your nonce to ensure the request is a valid and secure request - even IF the request is originating from the back-end, it still could be insecure or an attempt to exploit the system.

Also look at:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_admin_referer

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my question is more about multiple ajax request per one page. For example I have two buttons that send ajax request to admin - "update_calendar" and "get_date". Should I have separate nonce for every single request? Or for each button?